# Get Several Product Attributes as Columns on "catalog_product_entity"

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value, magento2.2

I'm trying to make a table that shows a list of products with various product attributes but I'm completely stuck with the way to do it.

Expected Table looks like below;

```
entity_id, sku, price, cost
        1, abc,    20,   15
        2, def,    30,   25
        3, ghi,    10,    5
```

Both product attributes below are stored in the same column "value" on the table  "catalog_product_entity_decimal"

```
Price: attribute_id = 77

Cost: attribute_id = 81
```

Thus, if I inner join tables, each entity_id has 2 lines for attribute_id 77 and 81

Could you please help me get over this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join the table for attribute  two time

```
select a.entity_id, a.sku, b.value price, c.value cost
from your_product_table a
inner join your_table_attribute b
  on a.entity_id = b.entity_id 
      AND b.attribute_id = 77
inner join  your_table_attribute c on a.entity_id = c.entity_id
      AND c.attribute_id = 81
where  a.entity_id = 1
```